# Any suggestions for this error : Notice: Undefined index: id

Tags: php, forms, get

Here's my updated code after following some of your suggestions, I have lost that error but now my form doesn't output the posts, are there any  suggestions for this?

```
<form method="get" action="wavy.php">
        <textarea name="postbody" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<?php 
include("connect.php");
$userid = "";
$username = ""; 
$id = "";
    if(isset($_GET['postbody'])) 
    {
        if(isset($_GET['id']))
        {
            if (connect::query('SELECT id FROM accounts')) {
                $userid = connect::query('SELECT id FROM accounts', array(':id'=>$_GET['id']))[0]['id'];
                $postbody = $_GET['postbody'];  

                connect::query('INSERT INTO posts VALUES (null, :postbody, NOW(), :userid, 0)', array(':postbody'=>$postbody, ':userid'=>$userid));   
            }  
            $dbposts = connect::query('SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC', array(':userid'=>$userid));
                $posts = "";
                foreach($dbposts as $p) {
                        $posts .= htmlspecialchars($p['body'])."
                        <form action='wavy.php' method='get'>
                                <input type='submit' name='like' value='Like'>
                        </form>
                        <hr /></br />
                        ";
            }    
        }
    }   


    if(isset($postbody))
    {
        echo $postbody;               
    }
?>
```

Comment: yep => http://stackoverflow.com/q/4261133/1415724 being a duplicate of this.

Comment: TIP: look at your 2nd form's action *very carefully*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: and this seems a repost of your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42990708/how-would-i-get-this-form-to-output-every-post-instead-of-just-the-newest-one

Comment: @Xorifelse I guess they still haven't gotten "it".

Comment: What on earth is going on here? `$userid = connect::query('SELECT id FROM accounts', array(':id'=>$_GET['id']))[0]['id'];`

Comment: any idea why my form won't output any posts?